# create object in a parent class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I'm coding a card game. How do I assign my already created cards to an object through the parent class?

I tried to create a new object with like this:

```
name = Card(suit1, face1, value1)
```

but since I declare the name before that it doesn't work properly.
If I print the names after I define the variable `name` the output is: `7Hearts, 7Diamonds, 7Clubs, 7Spades, 8Hearts, 8Diamonds...`
I want to create objects in the Card class, so that the expected output for
`print(7Hearts.suit, 7Hearts.face, 7Hearts.value)`
is

```
>>> (Hearts, 7, 7)
```

or for
`print(AceSpades.suit, AceSpades.face, AceSpades.value)`

```
>>> (Spades, Ace, 11)
```

```
from random import *
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, face, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.face = face
        self.value = value


class Deck(Card):
    def __init__(self):

        suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
        ranks = range(7, 15)
        for rank1 in ranks:
            for suit1 in suits:
                if rank1 == 11:
                    face1 = 'Jack'
                    value1 = 2
                elif rank1 == 12:
                    face1 = 'Queen'
                    value1 = 3
                elif rank1 == 13:
                    face1 = 'King'
                    value1 = 4
                elif rank1 == 14:
                    face1 = 'Ace'
                    value1 = 11
                else:
                    face1 = str(rank1)
                    value1 = rank1

                name = "{0}{1}".format(face1, suit1)
```

Comment: A `Deck` is not a kind of `Card`; it is a *collection* of cards. Don't use inheritance here.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here.  In the sample code you're not using the variable `name` for anything.  I also agree with @chepner, there is no reason to make `Deck` a subclass of `Card`.  It doesn't make any sense.  Perhaps you just want to make a list of `Card` objects?

Answer (score 2):

You neither need or want inheritance here. A `Deck` is simply a collection of cards.

```
class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades'],
        ranks = {11: 'Jack', 12: 'Queen', 13: 'King', 14: 'Ace'}
        values = {11: 2, 12: 3, 13: 4, 14: 11}
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in range(7,15):
                card_rank = ranks.get(rank, str(rank))
                value = values.get(value, value)
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, card_rank, value))
```

You might use inheritance to represent different *kinds* of decks: poker deck, pinochle deck, etc. `Deck` itself would have methods for things like shuffling, but each subclass would construct the `Card` objects appropriate for that deck.